# Lookahead containing the same token as left/right anchors

Tags: ruby, regex

Got a variation of the classic "regex quoted strings" problem. I need to pick out strings that look like this:

`"foo bar bar"`

from a long string like this

`token token "maybe quoted token that can also contain spaces"`

Each of the tokens can be quoted or unquoted (this is easy to take care of using alternating groups) but sometimes I have quoted strings which have literal quotes inside them (not escaped in any way),
the only useable thing being that those quotes never have spaces on either side (since that would
create a delimiter). Those tokens look like this: `"foo-bar"baz"`

My initial thought was `/"(?:[^"]|" )*"/` but that doesn't seem to work because a token like this: `"here is some"quotes"` gets split in two.

How should I do this? Platform is Ruby 2.1

Comment: In which language? In other words, are lookbehinds allowed?

Comment: Ruby 2.1 but would be nice to have it working on 1.9.3 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
"(?:[^"]|"\w)+"
```

or

```
"(?:[^"]|"\S)+"
```

You can play with sample strings in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/43).

**Explanation**

- `"` matches the opening quote
- The non-capturing group`(?:start [^"]|"\w)` matches...
- One `[^"]` non-quote character, OR `|`
- One quote and a word character `"\w`
- `+` one or more times
- `"` closing quote

**Further Refinements**

If you want to allow quotes in other contexts, for instance escaped quotes, just add them to the alternation:

```
"(?:\\"|[^"]|"\w)+"
```

To allow quotes to be followed not just by a word char but any non-space:

```
"(?:\\"|[^"]|"\S)+"
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a lookahead for this - `"(?:[^"]|"\S)+"` should do it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Just as I finished removing the lookahead while writing the explanation, I saw your comment. Agreed, no need. :)

Comment: FYI added options with some potential refinements, e.g. escaped quotes.

Comment: Almost, and very slick. For me it worked with non-space class instead of word-class: `"(?:[^"]|"(?=[^\s]))+"` because I also have `;` next to the quotes sometimes. And no, those files are not written by me :-)

Comment: Non-space was an option I considered, I gave you `\w` as a starting point. We don't need the lookahead, and what you sent can be simplified to `"(?:[^"]|"\S)+"` Will add that just below the `\w` answer :)

Comment: PS: the reason we don't need the lookahead (which I had for about 30 seconds before writing the explanation) is that we're going to match the character that follows anyway... so `"\S` is more compact than `"(?=\S)` (where the `\S` would get picked up by the `[^"]` on the next round. Going to bed but happy to answer any questions in the morning. :)

Answer (score 1):

This one may also suit your needs:

```
".*?"(?!\S)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YRtr-sMbLKfeOusH)

---

To match also non-quoted tokens:

```
".*?"(?!\S)|\S+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TRDy1_ZMbyGGAjPI)